# Azure Blob Storage Shared Access Signature (SAS) - Signature did not match

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I'm trying to deploy a VM by uploading an ARM Template and Parameters file into a private Blob storage container and then download them when needed. The files upload into the container fine, but when the trying to download them the SAS token fails to authenticate giving the error:

```
Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: 
Unable to download deployment content from 'https://cloudstationsbackendsa.blob.core.windows.net/workstation-templates/CreateVMTemplate.json?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=GHgWUiEG7bG3%2FDN4cjSsmHGrBTdM8F2LRxNTss5cJB0%3D&st=2019-03-06T11:16:42Z&se=2019-03-06T11:31:42Z&sp=r'
```

Visiting this URL in a browser produces the following error:

```
<Error>
<Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
<Message>
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:8e274bc1-101e-0011-3f0c-d45f43000000 Time:2019-03-06T11:03:53.3144543Z
</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>
Signature did not match. String to sign used was r 2019-03-06T10:58:39Z 2019-03-06T11:13:39Z /blob/cloudstationsbackendsa/workstation-templates/CreateVMTemplate.json 2018-03-28
</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

This is the method used to upload the files and generate the SAS tokens:

```
public async Task<StorageAccountAccessDTO> UploadTemplatesAsync(string azureIdentifier)
{
    // Access to Storage Account           
    var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_config.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:StorageAccount"));
    var serviceClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    var container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference("workstation-templates");

    // Upload VM ARM Template
    var templateBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("CreateVMTemplate.json");
    await templateBlob.UploadFromFileAsync("CreateVMTemplate.json");

    // Upload VM ARM Parameters
    var parameterBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("Parameters.json");
    await parameterBlob.UploadFromFileAsync("Parameters.json");

    // Create SAS Tokens
    SharedAccessBlobPolicy sasConstraints = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
    sasConstraints.SharedAccessStartTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5);
    sasConstraints.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10);
    sasConstraints.Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read;

    var accessDTO = new StorageAccountAccessDTO()
    {
        TemplateURL = templateBlob.Uri + templateBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints),
        ParametersURL = templateBlob.Uri + parameterBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints)
    };

    return accessDTO;
}
```

The SAS tokens are appended to the URI of the blob and returned in a StorageAccountAccessDTO, this is passed into the method below to produce the VM:

```
public async Task CreateVirtualMachineAsync(string azureIdentifier, StorageAccountAccessDTO accessDTO)
{
    await _azure.Deployments.Define("myDeployment")
        .WithExistingResourceGroup(azureIdentifier + "-RG")
        .WithTemplateLink(accessDTO.TemplateURL, "1.0.0.0")
        .WithParametersLink(accessDTO.ParametersURL, "1.0.0.0")
        .WithMode(DeploymentMode.Incremental)
        .CreateAsync();
}
```

Thanks for your time and let me know if you require any extra details!

Comment: What happens when you try to download the blob directly using SAS URL i.e. take the SAS URL and paste it in browser's address bar? Do you get error?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes thats actually where I retrieved the XML error from, I have updated the question to include the original error I recieved from the code for clarity. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the URL of `templateBlob` with a signature for `parameterBlob`.

Right there:

```cs
ParametersURL = templateBlob.Uri + parameterBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints)
```

It'll work better with the correct variable:

```cs
ParametersURL = parameterBlob.Uri + parameterBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints)
```

Cheers!

Comment: Must have overlooked this searching for a problem with the templateURL, its trying to download the template blob a second time for the parameters instead of the template file, stupid mistake by me, thanks for the help!